# psycopg2 with Postgres fetchall works but not execute

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to execute some `Postgres` queries with `psycopg2`.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="test.postgres.database.azure.com",
    database="postgres",
    user="test",
    password="test")
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = "select site_panel from test.ws_sites"

cur.execute(sql)
rows =  cur.fetchall()
```

The query above works well and returns the data but the following query does not delete the table as intended.

```
 cur.execute ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.ws_sites")
```

Anything wrong I'm doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query that modifies table data or schema structure needs to be committed:

```py
cur.execute ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.ws_sites")
conn.commit()
```

Alternatively, place

```py
conn.autocommit = True
```

after creating the connection.